# Is there a universal URI scheme for Facebook app, that works across all mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, uri, deep-linking

I'm trying to send marketing emails to users. The email design is responsive and will be opened on mobiles as well as desktops.

I want to put a link to my company's facebook page at the bottom of the email, and I want this link to behave differently on mobiles vs on desktops.

On mobile, the link should take the user to the facebook page within the facebook app, while on desktop it should take the user to the facebook page within the browser itself.

Our facebook page is https://www.facebook.com/gallerifive

So far I know this:

On iPhones, the URI fb://profile/1489743204605638 takes the user to galleri5 page within FB app (as required). On Android phones it throws an error.

On iPhones, the URI fb://page/1489743204605638 takes the user to Facebook app, and before anything can load, the FB app crashes! On Android phones, it opens up galleri5 page in the FB app (as required)

I know I can redirect Android and iPhone users differently based on their platform - but it sounds a bit strange that there is no universal URI scheme for Facebook that works on all mobile devices. Does anyone know more about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as I encounter a good number of people asking it still I figured I should post something.

This is functionality that could be created, but only Facebook is in a position to build it.

For such links to work on iOS, for example, they would have to function as Universal Links. This would require configuration within the Facebook app and Facebook would need to host an AASA file. You can read more about this here: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/.